# Build an interpreter for "Goggle kids Code"

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

Partially inspired by [this](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/204147/solution-to-google-kids-code) question.

### Overview

The execution of Goggle kids Code starts with an empty binary tape with 100 items, with the pointer starting at the index 0:

```
00000...
^
```

At the end of the execution, you can assume that the tape is implicitly outputted.

### Instructions

Goggle kids Code is a simple language involving a stack-like tape.

- `/`: Move the pointer right.
- `\`: Move the pointer left.
- `>`: Take two items from the tape, the left item and the current item. Zero the current item, move left, and set the item as 1 if `left` is larger than `current`, else 0.
- `=`: Similar to `>`, but performs an equality comparison instead.

The only looping structure in Goggle kids Code is the repeat loop, which takes a *strictly positive* number on the right introduced by a `x` symbol. (So things like `(...)x0` is impossible here.) The syntax for this is:

```
(...)xI
```

The parentheses can only contain single instructions, although you can introduce other instructions with commas.

### Sample program + Explanation

```
((/,>)x4,/)x13

(         )x13  Do this 13 times:
 (   )x4            Do this 4 times:
  /                    Move right
   ,                   After that,
    >                  Greater than
        ,           After that,
         /          Move pointer right.
```

Another example that does something useful (fills 13 items from the tape with 1's):

```
(   )x13    Do this 13 times:
 /              Move right
  ,             After that,
   =            Equality
```

### Rules

- You can assume the tape pointer never wraps around.

  - The test cases won't abuse out-of-bounds tape-moving.
- To simplify the solution, you are allowed to output part of the tape, as long as that part is modified.
- You are allowed to have a different instruction mapping, but if you do that, please make sure to clarify which mapping you used.
- You could ignore checking the commas in the source code, they'll always be there.

  - Instructions are always separated by the comma.

### Test cases

The trailing `0` digits are omitted here, for compactness of example outputs.

````
((/,>)x4,/)x13  -> 0000000000000 (doesn't modify the tape)

(/,=,/)x13      -> 1111111111111

(/,=,/,/)x13    -> 1010101010101010101010101

(/,=)x13,/,=    -> 00000000000000000

(/,/,=,\)x3     -> 0100
```
````

Comment: Also, a link to where we can learn more about "Goggle kids Code" is much appreciated. I have tried searching for the term, but couldn't find any thing relevant. I also can't see the linked question, it says 404 not found.

Comment: Will the test case always have a loop out most? If not, suggest `(/,=)x13,/,=` as a test case.

Comment: Relevant: [Google doodle - Turing machine](https://www.google.com/doodles/alan-turings-100th-birthday). That's the closest thing I could find.

Comment: So Google is teaching kids Brainfuck?  I approve!

Comment: @Jonah I guess Google is teaching Boolfuck instead of Brainfuck.

Comment: Where you say "and set the item as 1 if left > current", I assume the `>` refers to ordinary numeric comparison and this isn't some sort of evil recursive definition?

Comment: @JDL Sorry about the confusion, I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: @SurculoseSputum I think I fixed that (I haven't tested out the link because the network I'm on has blocked it) by changing it to the Wayback Machine.

Comment: Assuming loops can be infinite, is this Turing-complete?

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Prove it yourself, I have no idea...

Comment: I now realized it is not, because it cannot access infinite memory (either the infinite loop is "balanced" - that is, has equally many ``\`` and `/`, and thus a finite amount of memory, or it is not "balanced" and all memory eventually becomes unreachable at the same rate it becomes reachable, so still a finite amount of memory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 89 bytes

```ruby
t=[i=0]*100;(eval"[#$_]").flatten.map{|x|x<2?t[i-=1,2]=[x==t[i]-t[i+1]?1:0,0]:i+=x-3};p t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYlBDoIwFET3ngIrixZaaIEV@OEgpSGYYNIEgWA1NerVrWWns5i8N7PeTg8XdolZ9wHCxELd@qSIBkiqiIusQM6A1MBVJDiv8HDvRyQPYacQSc5jb8wwJZd@eb7syx6zxkjNQNBMgbQA3hTzFQvViJJTrkodg2X5u1oC4xzGKa2JLWhKrMh33uAPf2QDP8Am29cSm3/mxeh5ujo2fQE)

The translation map of the characters used for instructions is indicated in TIO header.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>131 126 123 110</s> 104 bytes

*Saved 13 bytes thanks to @dingledooper's approach of flattening nested list using backtick.*
*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @l4m2*

```python
p,t=0,[0]*100
for i in`input()`:
 if"/"<i:i=int(i);p+=i/3-1
 if i<2:t[p:p+2]=cmp(*t[p:p+2])==i,0
print t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NctBCoMwEEbhfU4RXCUxxUkEF6lzEhGEgvRfNA4yLnr6tF10@fh48tbnUXNrEpUpLrSGRGT247SwqBuqXOr8VozF3g3djAJGVQd/l54xjLf0I4s5F12kSJ9XfrzEhX95ZkQycn43q625KVKcfEjjBw) or [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##dZFNbsIwEIX3PsXIG2wwxAlVFynmIoCUEEI7VX6s2G1DL5@OUwKoUscb2@@bN8@Jvfi3tkmGoj2VYKDjnA9WeaPVTh/msdbs3HaAgE2Gjf3wQmYpAzzziG8wRYONFyhf7MJgtF7GQQLcJKnf2dQukoMpaivm00kag0oz21EbcL56b7ER2aLPIEzpaQp4OVAGxtylPraVo0wnLLz4RisY8Gi/NUL2XNH@OYm1kHPOpGQMa9t2HtzFjYErbMrgRueV8ydsKDQ4BXnjvsqOTOvcCuc7Eju0auRXzlboxWy5nZEj4YRNGa9pVq@lF4Uq5Ji3GCcEdPw0hFd5fTzlKZSfeSVG5fpU87f4TXO0K/uygPALbre/Qe8GfBAiUlvZP6lI9vEaYLkF/ViMdDOJoQiIH@sK3JEA6H/WCAeQGswV1n8rQMFzL/v1NJKa9Q8)

Takes input from `STDIN`, where `/\>=x` are replaced with `6210*`

#### Big idea:

Python 2 `input()` implicitly evaluates the string read from `STDIN`. Thus, reading modified input like `((6,1)*4,2)*13` returns a nested tuple of integers, aka

```python
((6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1), 2, (6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1), 2, ...)
```

Note that loops containing single instruction must be terminated with comma, e.g `(1,)*10`.

Now that all loops have been automatically unrolled for us, we just have to flatten the resulting tuple, and decode the instructions.

To flatten the nested tuple, we simply convert it to string, then takes all numerical characters.

Comment: @dingledooper Very clever approach, using back tick to flatten nested lists. Thanks!

Comment: `p+=i/3-1` using 6 as /

Comment: Do rule allow **print**ing a mix of `0` and `false`?

Comment: @l4m2 I'm not sure about this, but since `False` *is* `0`, I see no reason this is not allowed.

Comment: but `"False"` is *not* `"0"`

Comment: It's generally been allowed.

Comment: @l4m2 I worded it poorly. `False` is considered functionally identical to `0`, as per [consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9067/92237). I'm not too sure about the mixing of `False` and `0`, but I don't think that's a big problem.

Comment: @xnor It's printed and therefore we get string, and without `eval` I don't see any relation

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 149 bytes

```javascript
s=>eval(`[${s.replace(/ \d+/g,'.toString().repeat($&)')}]+6`).replace(/\d/g,c=>c>4?p+=c-6:(X[p-1]=X[p-1]-X[p]==c,X[p--]=0),X=Array(100).fill(p=0))&&X
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY1Na4NAFEX3/RVZBN97OI5K0xSEZ@k@u24EI3EYPzBYFbXBkuS325FQUkg3c3jnXuYe1UkNuq@60WnaLJ8LngcO85OqMY3X50H2eVcrnaO72me2WwqQY/sx9lVTIi1hrkZcWwR0TextSvf@PjNtzaEON2@dzdrZBhjFneMnfINjkDBrsZxOwh6JiN/7Xn2j73kki6qusTOaLCua@6@GJ/Nb2wxtncu6LbHA6T4nb2t4BoYAPBCwg@BFQAiBL8CF4FUAmiQ2CRkmhsJweSfDFVwp1snloonkp@rwwKF9IHlsqyZN6cnsIyC6IqRpI1ya/Gf4ta7g/8yjW27j@Y9bmjualtr8Aw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 135 bytes

```
,

\d+
$*
+`\([^()]+\)x|(?<=\(([^()]+)\)x1*)1
$1
^
0
{`(\d)/(\D*)((1)|0)?
$1$#4$2
(\d)\\(\D*)
$2$1
(?=(10>|(.)\2=))?.\d[>=](\D*)
$#1$+0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xDsIwDEV3X6NB@m6qNikdSbMgcYi6VZHKwMKAGCrRuwcHdYDt//ds2c/b6/64pgMuc6qIZLFkSrKzYJjAoxVeN8RTEOyAlfiSPRlPEzl6z5CFG8i5ZMDz5jiqM0VnWspK5OvItLqBGOBdv6FmaQNzrGUZ@jDuI4U31qUENFXPa1c1eutI2sJf/Ck5KAi5ZKffHT8) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
,
```

Delete commas.

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the multipliers to unary.

```
+`\([^()]+\)x|(?<=\(([^()]+)\)x1*)1
$1
```

Expand all repetitions from the inside out. (The last two stages can be performed by a single stage in Retina 1 at a saving of 19 bytes although you do then have to use `${3}` instead of `$+` in the last stage.)

```
^
0
```

Start with a tape with a `0`. (The tape is automatically extended to the right as necessary, as this was slightly golfier than predefining the tape..)

```
{`
```

Process the instructions until they have all been executed.

```
(\d)/(\D*)((1)|0)?
$1$#4$2
```

Move right, extending the tape as necessary.

```
(\d)\\(\D*)
$2$1
```

Move left.

```
(?=(10>|(.)\2=))?.\d[>=](\D*)
$#1$+0
```

(In)equality. (`$+` is used instead of `$3` because the next character is a digit.)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 235 bytes

```javascript
p=>{s=[],l=Array(13).fill(i=q=0),e={'(':`s.unshift(1,i)`,')':`++s[0]<=parseInt(p.substr(i+1))?i=s[1]:s.splice(0,2)`,'/':`q++`,'\\':`q--`,'>':`l[q]=0,q--`,'=':`l[q]=0,q--,l[q]=+!l[q]`};while(i<p.length)eval(e[p[i++]]);return l.join('')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY/RbsIgFIbv9xTOG84JSMvclYrLLvcMbRM7hxZDKELrXIzP3lGXLKuLHi748iffD2dXHsqw9to1E1t/qM63VnZOLk9BZgUz8tX78gvEFPlGGwNa7mWKTMkTATJbBd7aUOlNA4JpXDGCMaQ0ZGmxkK70Qb3ZBhwP7XtoPGgqEF@0DJkoZoEHZ/RaQcqeejWJ6p7SSHne42QScRnJZPtCpuwnkIOAXZA@9tfqPP@stFGgF44bZbdNhepQGlCZyzSlRYFzr5rW25Hhu1pbIATP3bq2oTaKm3oLcXkYAyRsicdnluBRTMfIRiS36WByS3D@8N9MmBxY4u/ct4Zeeuvc6ej92CMvHaOrL9/2@tfzHI@/m4prrfsG)

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 231 bytes

```javascript
p=>{s=[],l=Array(13).fill(i=q=0),e={'(':`s.unshift(1,i)`,')':`++s[0]<=parseInt(p.substr(i+1))?i=s[1]:s.splice(0,2)`,'/':`q++`,'\\':`q--`,'>':`l[--q]=0`,'=':`l[q]=0,l[--q]=+!l[q]`};while(i<p.length)eval(e[p[i++]]);return l.join('')}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/BbsIwDIbvewrGJbaSps3YCQjTjnuGthIdCzQoSkPSMibEs3cpmibYNDT78v@Wvt/2ttpXYeW1axPbvKned1b2Ti6OQeYlM/LZ@@oDxAT5WhsDWu5khkzJIwEyXQbe2VDrdQuCaVwygnFIacizci5d5YN6sS04HrrX0HrQVCA@aRlyUU4DD87olYKMPQxoGtEdpVEVxSCTJMpFVCZPkl0ps2jl2Q6GfU3p/eCXp9l7rY0CPXfcKLtpa1T7yoDKXa4pLUucedV23o4M3zbaAiF46leNDY1R3DQbiI/DGCBlCzw8shQPYjJGNiKFzS6rsARnd7/BlMkrSFzWbeqay/7qGxkDH3PkOWP074uH7UWBh@9HxU@s/wQ)